# How do you know the value of the parameter in this javascript function ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have this function :

```
d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
        //console.log('change mod pos ...');
        // Because the node should remain fixed, the previous position (.px, .py)
        // needs to be set to the same value as the new position (.x, .y). This way
        // the node will not have any inherent movement.
        move.x = move.px = interpolateX(elapsed / duration); 
        move.y = move.py = interpolateY(elapsed / duration); 

        // Re-calculate the force layout. This will also invoke tick()
        // which will take care of the rendering.
        force.start();

        // Terminate the timer when the desired duration has elapsed.
        return elapsed >= duration;
    });
```

It can be found in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/smqsusdw/1/

Notice the parameter 'elapsed'. Where does this function get that value from ? Does it get it from the 'd3.timer' ?

Obviously I don't know the ins and outs of javascript so i think im missing something totally obvious here.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation: https://github.com/d3/d3-timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're correct in that assumption. When the `d3.timer` function calls the anonymous function (`function(elapsed) {...}`), it will pass something to that function as the first parameter. I'm not exactly sure what `d3.timer` does without digging into the code but it does something like this:

```
d3.timer = function(anonFunc) {
    var elapsed = 0;
    // Some code that does something to elapsed
    anonFunc(elapsed);
}
```

You can find out what is being passed back to the anonymous function by using `console.log(elapsed);` at the beginning of the function. You can see what d3.timer does by typing in `d3.timer` in your browser's Javascript console.

Answer (score 1):

> `timer(callback[, delay[, time]])`
>
> The callback is passed two arguments each time it is invoked: the elapsed time since the timer became active, and the current time. The latter is useful for precise scheduling of secondary timers.
>
> https://github.com/d3/d3-timer

D3 basically uses [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) and [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to call your callback after the delay ms with the following signature:

```
timer(function(elapsed, time) {
  console.log(elapsed, time);
  return elapsed > 200;
}, 150);
```

You can also use the [Arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to see what parameters a function has been passed.

```
var x = function(){ console.log(arguments) };
x(1,2)
> [1, 2]
```

Comment: I would recommend that you play around with setInterval and setTimeout as it is pretty good way to figure out how callbacks and asynchronous programming in general works.